# c++ pound define with only one argument

Tags: c++

I see a strange use of pound define (#define) in a cpp code such as:

```
#define FUNCTION
```

Yeah, this is it.
and for all function definitions.
the code is like

```
FUNCTION int foo_add(int a, int b) {}
```

what is the purpose this, and what is this?
Thanks!

Comment: It's a placeholder.  This provides a mechanism for someone to do something like `#define FUNCTION __stdcall` (or something) in the future, and have it apply instantly to all marked functions.

Comment: Not enough context to answer this.

Comment: You'll need to ask the author of that particular piece of code, any answer given here regarding its purpose would be pure speculation.

Answer (score 4):

Since `FUNCTION` expands to nothing, it looks like some sort of annotation for some other tool than C++ compiler.

Answer (score 1):

```
#define identifier token-string
```

*A #define without a token-string removes occurrences of identifier from the source file. The identifier remains defined and can be tested by using the #if defined and #ifdef directives.*